# I need change input's value and submit form within this value

Tags: javascript, submit, developer-tools

I need change input's value and submit form within this value. But i cant. I tried in console. You can review website's login page and you can try like me from console (f12/`developer tools`). Thanks

Visit : https://www.papara.com/personal/#!/register

My Code :

```
$('input[name=FirstName]').val('text');
```

`"Hesap Olustur"` -> Create Accaount Clicked.

Comment: `$('input[name=FirstName]').val('text');` puts "text" in the first field, so it appears to be working as expected. What's your issue?

Comment: you are right but this irrelevant with my issue. When i click login (submit button) the program is catch what im do.  So im trying change the value and submit but i have an error "this input must be filled". I trying changing value without error

Answer (score 0):

you can add `event.preventDefault()` on `formsubmit` event

then change your value

then run `form.submit()` again